# Modify XMLHttpRequests to make them cross domain

Tags: jquery, cross-domain

I am working on a proxy for an application. I need to convert all the AJAX calls on a particular page to be cross domain so that my proxy can complete those ajax calls.

I was looking into possibility of binding JQuery.beforeSend with window and have three questions:

1. How can I actually add extra parameter of dataType: jsonp; to all the AJAX calls that are present on the page.
2. Will this bind the function with all the XMLHttpRequests or only the requests done via jQuery $.ajax , $.get, $.post, etc functions
3. If I add dataType: jsonp; will it only add this to calls done via jQuery or all the calls done via any library or originating from browser

Is there a better way to do it. Any other recommendations to over come this problem. Since I wont be knowing the external HTML, changing the URL it calls via AJAX is more harder and hence routing it via my proxy domain is not a preferred way in my case.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You could shadow the existing jQuery method...

   ```
   var jQueryAjax = $.ajax;

   $.ajax = function(settings) {
      settings.type = 'jsonp';
      jQueryAjax(settings);
   }
   ```

   I *think* this should work.
2. `ajax()` is the low level interface for AJAX requests in jQuery, but I'm not sure if they call it. `getJSON()` seems to call `get()`.
3. Adding `jsonp` will only be useful if the service you are using supports JSONP.

Comment: Hello Alex,
Thanks, How about if I add an extra header (origin:) to all the request. If I add the domain of the page where the Request is going, will that help?

Answer (score 0):

1. set the datatype to jsonp ( dataType: "jsonp")
2. With jsonp you can only handle GET request, see 3.
3. Only to the call where you added jsonp as datatype

Comment: Hello Ivo, Thanks, How about if I add an extra header (origin:) to all the request. If I add the domain of the page where the Request is going as the Origin header, will that help?